# Find out if package.json includes all the necessary dependancies

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I just inherited an Angular 2/ Redux project. There are countless packages in ng_modules, and I'd like to get rid of some. `npm prune` cannot work because package.json does not include all the necessary dependencies. Is there a way to check if any necessary dependencies are missing from the package.json? I think I know how to check for unnecessary ones.

Comment: Necessary respect to your currently installed packages or to the packages actually required by your application?

Comment: @toomuchdesign the packages actually required by my application.